# New Chrome profile: how can I migrate all browser data from one profile to another?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, user-profiles, migration, auto-form-fill

I've had a good look for about an hour on this and have come up blank. Apologies in advance if I'm wasting everybody's time with an elementary question. Running Windows 7.

I've created a new Chrome profile that I want to use in preference to my old one. I'd like to migrate history, extensions, cache, saved passwords, form fill data etc from old to new. I migrated bookmarks exporting/importing an HTML file, but after that I'm stuck. I did find this http://goo.gl/mXsDdt but the UI's changed and I can't duplicate the instructions. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

PS: Tangent, but this is connected to a move from Gmail to a personalised domain, paid Google Apps account, chosen in part (stupidly and naively) because I imagined the transition would be within Google and therefore simple. An hour with tech support, 3rd party software, imports and exports, manual mail migration. Might as well have been taking stuff across PCs with Outlook 2003.

Comment: Referencing the "moving from gmail to paid google apps' part: [Got Your Back](https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/wiki) makes moving messages including labels very easy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some excessive research, I came across [this article](http://www.inteligentcomp.com/2013/07/move-entire-google-chrome-data-from-one-account-to-another.html) that I believe is what you are looking for.

Here is the essential information from the link:

> In this Post I’ll show you how you can move entire Google Chrome Data
>   including History, Bookmarks, passwords, Saved Cookies etc. from one
>   Google Account to another and that too offline, you can Sync It online
>   anytime after that.  Hello Everyone, Got new mail id right? Now want
>   to get your Google Chrome Data, Settings, and Bookmarks from your old
>   account to new account? It’s easy to get everything back on new
>   account and there are several ways to move bookmarks but you really
>   need this post if you want to move History, Bookmarks, Saved
>   passwords, Settings in your Google chrome and all.
>
> Well let’s get ahead saying you have now two mail IDs, oldid@gmail.com
>   and newid@gmail.com.  You are currently signed Google chrome as
>   oldid@gmail.com and want to move entire data to newid@gmail.com. So
>   what you need to do is, sign in to Google chrome using your new ID.
>   Yeah its newid@gmail.com  For this  Open Chrome://Settings In Users
>   section, click on Add new user.. Choose the Icon and Sign in to new
>   user account in your Google chrome. Lets this name as newuser, So you
>   have two user in your chrome say olduser and newuser.   You have
>   entire data in your olduser and want to move to newuser.  Just tap
>   Windows key+R to open run In Run type appdata  Now open
>   \Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\  Let me tell you, now in this user
>   data folder, you can see two folder name Default and profile1 Default
>   folder contains entire data of Profile0 that is olduser.     And
>   profile1 contains the Entire data of newuser.  You can open default
>   and see the list of files named Application data Extensions Jump list
>   Google profile icon History Last session, Open tab And so many olduser
>   account related data.
>
> Now all you have to copy or move these all data (in case you want to
>   transfer entire data) else selected data like history and session etc
>   from \default\ to \profile1\  Now open Google chrome’s new profile See
>   the entire data is present in your new chrome user. How to Transfer
>   Google chrome data from one Account to another account online.  What
>   we have done is Moved Data from older account to new account in local
>   computer. It’s still not available in online account. To do this: Just
>   let the Google chrome sync the data once it get online and your Entire
>   data will be saved to your new Google chrome account with
>   newid@gmail.com username.  It’s really helpful those who are migrating
>   from one Gmail account to another.
>
> Bottom line  This is really very helpful and easy method to do so, you
>   can go to similar location in your older version like Windows XP and
>   all.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant information from the link?

Comment: Hi variable1knife, thanks for that, worked a charm.

Comment: Don't forget to change the email in the binary files to the new email. Use a binary search and replace tool

Comment: Not working on recent versions

Comment: Worked fine for me just now, however it still asks to sign into that users account. Simply just sign out of that account and make sure to select to NOT delete the data and then it's a local account.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the following method to duplicate a profile in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge (v87).

**Use the browser sync function to move data from one profile to another.** Chrome and Edge do not let you sign in to two profiles at once with the same account, but if you sign in and sync one profile, sign out, then sign in and sync the second profile with the same account, the data should copy over.

1. Create the first profile and set it up, add extensions, etc.
2. Turn on sync and sign in. Wait a few minutes for your settings and extensions to upload.
3. Turn off sync and sign out (don't check the box to clear existing data).
4. Create the second profile.
5. Sign in and sync browser data. Your settings and extensions are downloaded and applied.
6. Sign out.
7. The two profiles should now be nearly identical (not all settings are migrated via sync).

Answer (score 2):

Please note that if you are trying to do this to read the article as it now is not working with current versions of Chrome. Here is the update notice from the article:

> **UPDATE**:
>   Latest version of chrome doesn't support this, if you are using chrome v55+, this will not work, please manually movie bookmark by import/export and few files like history and all.
>   Since Moving files like this also insecure for saved passwords and other account preferences.
>   If you are still using older version of chrome, go ahead and read it.
>   once you move your file, make sure to update chrome to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with spreading out all your data with global players, you can nowadays...

- set up Microsoft Edge
- when it asks for importing data from other browsers, you choose Google Chrome
- then back in Chrome you add a new profile and when asked you import data from Edge

Although in general this works with the caveat of MS then having your data too, for me it did not work out using the same Google account.
So you would need to have another email adress/account.