# How can I get Chrome passwords from an SSD?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, user-profiles, password-recovery

Is it possible to get passwords from an inactive user profile directory? The user is not synced, I only have the SSD of the original system. Copying the profile directory into a live install doesn’t work. I looked at password tools on github which they seem to all require that I use the same system, but that system is unbootable.

I’m using Windows 10.

Update:

When I tried moving the profile directory into Chrome’s user data directory, it wouldn’t show up. When I tried creating a new profile and replacing the contents with contents of the old directory, I got this notice:

> Some settings were reset
>   Chrome detected that some of your settings were corrupted by another program and reset them to their original defaults. Learn more

The bookmarks and history are there, but not the passwords.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't believe copying the Google user profile from the SSD to the current Windows installation (same directory) can be done? I have migrated the same Chrome profile from three different seperate machines.  **These were all offline profiles.**

Comment: @Ramhound see my update.

Comment: I suspect what has happen is the passwords were encrypted with your Windows credentials, and since your new Chrome profile is unable to decrypt those files, they cannot be imported.  I have found a possible duplicate to this question, with a solution, that I know will work in the case you describe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1388955/import-chrome-user-profile-from-another-computer

Comment: @Ramhound I’m seeing a very informative answer in the linked linked question as well as a suggestion to try nirsoft’s ChromePass and SecurePassword Kit. I still would like to know if there is an open source tool or explanation of how to decrypt data from CryptProtectData on another machine.

Comment: Since I believe this to be a duplicate, and I don't recomend software, I am not going to suggest an open source alternative to ChromePass.

Comment: @Ramhound Understood. Clearly nirsoft is doing it somehow, if it were open source we could see how. The other answer and linked documentation made it seem like it would be impossible to decrypt on a different machine. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: Questions seeking software recomendations are out of scope here at Super User.  It is not clear if you have ruled out ChromePass, due to the fact it does not work, instead of the fact it isn't open source.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to know what’s going on under the hood. An open source tool would be one way to do that. Should I ask on a different site?